# Sonata Admin Bundle: for create new, how can I have user already selected?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I have two (2) Admins, UserAdmin and CarAdmin. From the list view of UserAdmin, I want to have a custom action that redirects to CarAdmin **create view** **with the user already selected.**

So far I have managed to create a custom action with its controller. My challenge is to redirect to CarAdmin create/new form passing some parameters for data persistence.

Any points of reference will be much appreciated. 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonata Admin allows to resolve such task pretty easy, no need to make a custom action. One of the solutions could be:

- Define a [custom template](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html) for one column in UserAdmin list view, render a special button(link) in it. A link should lead to CarAdmin create action with some get parameter.
- In CarAdmin in method [getNewInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546168/setting-default-value-in-symfony2-sonata-admin-bundle) check that if there is a special get parameter - set user with that ID. This step can also be done in methods getFormFields(), prePersist(), etc.

Some code samples:

*In UserAdmin*

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('actions', 'string', array(
            'template' => 'your_template_name.html.twig',
            'mapped' => false,
            )
       );
}
```

*In your_template_name.html.twig*

```
<a href="{{ path('route_of_the_car_admin_create', {user: object.id}) }}">Create Car for this user</a>
```

*In CarAdmin*

```
public function getNewInstance()
{
    $car= parent::getNewInstance();

    $userId = $this->getRequest()->query->get('user');
    if ($userId) {
        $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager(User::class);
        $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
        $car->setUser($user);
    }
    return $car;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.