# How to set selected option on choiceType sonata admin bundle

Tags: selected, sonata, symfony-3.4

**setting default/ selected option for choice field** in symfony3 sonata admin bundle?

For example :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
  parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);

  $formMapper->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'config.label_type',
    'choices' => [
      'config.label_permanent' => 'permanent',
      'config.label_automatic' => 'automatic',
      'config.label_temporary' => 'temporary' 
    ],
    'required' => false
  ]);
}
```

How to make the `_permanent_` as selected value ?

This post doesn't help me out
[setting default value in symfony2 sonata admin bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546168/setting-default-value-in-symfony2-sonata-admin-bundle/51305613#51305613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
  parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);

  $subject = $this->getSubject();
   if (null === $subject->getId()) {
     $subject->setType('permanent');
   }

  $formMapper->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'config.label_type',
    'choices' => [
      'config.label_permanent' => 'permanent',
      'config.label_automatic' => 'automatic',
      'config.label_temporary' => 'temporary' 
    ],
    'required' => false
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks mate :) . just one correction I have made that,
_$this->admin->getSubject();_  should be **$this->getSubject();**